# banner test ads are showing perfectly but real ads are not showing android app

Tags: admob, banner, banner-ads

i tried many searches on google but can not find proper solution.
please tell me how to handle

**I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3**

**please provide the solution**

Ad request are made but impression are not.....!!!

Comment: request are 511 but imapresion is 0...

Comment: please provide more details, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask